# Fixed joint not working properly

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everyone! I'm new in Gazebo. I created a laser rangefinder model and a robot model in which I want to use it. When I try to fix the imported model with fixed joint or revolute joint with 0 limit, and start the simulation, Gazebo shows the following:

[image: image description]

If I don't use any joints, the sensor just falls far down. Without a sensor, the robot looks normal during the simulation, as it should:

[image: image description]

Listing of laser model.sdf file:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version='1.6'>
  <model name="VL6180">
    <link name='body'>    
      <visual name='visual'>
        <pose>-0.0024 -0.0014 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <uri> model://VL6180/meshes/STL/VL6180X.stl </uri>
            <scale> .001 .001 .001 </scale>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <collision name='collision'>
        <pose> 0 0 .0005  0 0 0 </pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>.0048 .0028 .001</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <mass>0.00003</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.00000000000000001</ixx>
          <ixy>0.00000000000000001</ixy>
          <ixz>0.00000000000000001</ixz>
          <iyy>0.00000000000000001</iyy>
          <iyz>0.00000000000000001</iyz>
          <izz>0.00000000000000001</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <sensor type="ray" name="sensor">
        <pose>0.0018 0 0 0 -1.5708 0</pose>
          <visualize>true</visualize>
          <update_rate> 30 </update_rate>
          <ray>
            <scan>
              <horizontal>
                <samples>50</samples>
                <resolution>1</resolution>
                <min_angle>-0.174533</min_angle>
                <max_angle>0.174533</max_angle>
              </horizontal>
              <vertical>
                <samples>50</samples>
                <resolution>1</resolution>
                <min_angle>-0.174533</min_angle>
                <max_angle>0.174533</max_angle>
              </vertical>
            </scan>
            <range>
              <min>0.000001</min>
              <max>0.6</max>
            </range>
          </ray>
      </sensor>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

Listing of robot model.sdf file:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version='1.6'>
  <model name="my_robot">
    <frame name="robot"></frame>
    
    <pose>0 0 0.25 0 0 0</pose>
   <!-- <include>
      <name>laser_1</name>
      <uri>model://VL6180</uri>
      <pose>0 0.0425 .003 3.14159 0 3.14159</pose>
    </include>
 -->

    <link name='sole'>
      <pose>0 0 0 1.5708 0 0</pose>
      <visual name='sole_visual'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <uri> model://Robot_model/meshes/STL/Sole.stl </uri>
            <scale> .001 .001 .001 </scale>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </visual>

      <collision name='sole_collision_box'>
        <pose> 0 .049 0   -1.5708 0 0 </pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>.026 .016 .068</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>

      <collision name='sole_collision_cylinder'>
        <pose> 0 .0075 0   -1.5708 0 0 </pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <radius>.05</radius>
            <length>.015</length>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </collision>

      <inertial>
        <pose>0 .0128 0  0 0 0</pose>
        <mass>.370</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.000270821</ixx>
          <ixy>0.00</ixy>
          <ixz>0.00</ixz>
          <iyy>0.000402393</iyy>
          <iyz>0.00000</iyz>
          <izz>0.000273382</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
    </link>

    <link name = 'cross'>
      <pose>0 0 0.0725 0 0 1.5708</pose>

      <visual name='cross_visual'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <uri> model://Robot_model/meshes/STL/Cross.stl </uri>
            <scale> .01 .01 .01 </scale>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </visual>

      <collision name='cross_collision'>
        <pose> 0 0 .0025 0 0 0 </pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>.022 .014 .005</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
        <pose>0 0 .0025  0 0 0</pose>
        <mass>0.006</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>1.63e-07</ixx>
          <ixy>0.00</ixy>
          <ixz>0.00</ixz>
          <iyy>3.34e-07</iyy>
          <iyz>0.00000</iyz>
          <izz>4.75e-07</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
    </link>
    
    <link name = 'base'>
      <pose>0 -.017 .1 -1.5708 0 0</pose>
      <visual name='base_visual'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <uri> model://Robot_model/meshes/STL/Holder.stl </uri>
            <scale> .01 .01 .01 </scale>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
      </visual>

      <collision name='base_collision'>
        <pose> 0 .0155 .017 0 0 0 </pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>.012 .031 .034</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <inertial>
        <pose>0 .011117 0.017  0 0 0</pose>
        <mass>0.015</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.00000354</ixx>
          <ixy>0.00</ixy>
          <ixz>0.00</ixz>
          <iyy>0.000002528</iyy>
          <iyz>0.00000</iyz>
          <izz>0.000001378</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name = "sole_to_cross" type = "revolute">
      <pose>0 .075 0  -1.5708 0 0</pose>
      <parent>cross</parent>
      <child>sole</child>
      <axis>
        <xyz> 1 0 0 </xyz>

        <limit>
          <lower>-0.698132</lower>
          <upper>0.698132</upper>
        </limit>
      </axis>
      
    </joint> 

    <joint name = "cross_to_base" type = "revolute">
      <pose>.011 0 .0025 0 0 -1.5708</pose>
      <parent>base</parent>
      <child>cross</child>
      <axis>
        <xyz> 0 1 0 </xyz>

        <limit>
          <lower>-0.698132</lower>
          <upper>0.698132</upper>
        </limit>
      </axis>
      
    </joint>

   <!-- <joint name = "fix_laser_1" type = "fixed">
      <parent>sole</parent>
      <child>laser_1::body</child>
    </joint>
  -->

    <joint name = "base_to_ground" type = "fixed">
      <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
      <parent>world</parent>
      <child>base</child>
    </joint> 
    

  </model>
</sdf>
```

If anyone knows how to fix this please reply.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25043/fixed-joint-not-working-properly/) by [Aslan_k](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26413/aslan_k/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You need to fix the laser inertia (and fine tune the position of the model).

Try this one (it's the inertia of the collision box)

```
<inertial>
  <pose>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
  <mass>0.03</mass>
  <inertia>
    <ixx>2.21000000e-08</ixx>
    <ixy>0.000000</ixy>
    <ixz>0.000000</ixz>
    <iyy>6.01000000e-08</iyy>
    <iyz>0.000000</iyz>
    <izz>7.72000000e-08</izz>
  </inertia>
</inertial>
```

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2020-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aslan_k](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26413/aslan_k/) on 2020-05-10**:
nlamprian, thanks for your answer, its worked! I added this code to inertia tag:

```
<inertial>
        <pose>0 0 0.0005 0 0 0</pose>
        <mass>0.00003</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>2.21000000e-11</ixx>
          <ixy>0.000000</ixy>
          <ixz>0.000000</ixz>
          <iyy>6.01000000e-11</iyy>
          <iyz>0.000000</iyz>
          <izz>7.72000000e-11</izz>
        </inertia>
 </inertial>
```

**Comment by [Aslan_k](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/26413/aslan_k/) on 2020-05-10**:
I also wanted to know why Gazebo reacted so much to my past code, and what do you mean by "You need to fix the laser inertia (and fine tune the position of the model)." ?

**Comment by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) on 2020-05-10**:
You can think of inertias as the one thing that makes or breaks a model. If something is wrong, your model can collapse or explode.
For the position of the laser, in my test, the beams collided with the sole. If it's fine for you, then forget about it.